# MySQL: Calculate Winning Spree

Tags: mysql

I have the following table:

```
mysql> describe match_bet_log;
+---------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field         | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| matchId       | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| nick          | char(25)            | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| teamId        | tinyint(3) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
| correct_guess | tinyint(1)          | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
| dt            | datetime            | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
+---------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

I'm trying to calculate a "winning spree" for `nick`. The winning spree amount would be calculated by these parameters:

**Given a nick, return the amount of correct_guess=True up to their first correct_guess=False using dt to start from the newest correct_guess logged.**

Any help in calculating this "winning spree" purely in MySQL would be great. I know how to pull all of this data into python and parse and compute a winning spree that way but I'm looking for a more graceful way that can be done completely in MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

try this query and give a feedback:

```
select t.nic, count(t.correct_guess) from
table_name t
where t.correct_guess=1
and t.dt > (select max(tb.dt) from table_name tb 
          where tb.correct_guess=0 and tb.matchId=t.matchId)
group by t.nic
```